# Access Session by ActionFilterAttribute in .NET CORE

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I tried to access the session-value by using the ActionFilterAttribute in .NET CORE. Therefore i use the following code:

A normal .NET Core Controller which gets the annotation [SessionCheck].

```
[SessionCheck]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

These class is extended by the ActionFilterAttribute Class and overrides the OnActionExecuted Method, where i would like to access the session value. Is there a possibility? I could only access the Key but not the session value.

```
public class SessionCheck:ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var session = context.HttpContext.Session;
        //var mySessionValue = session["user"];
    }
}
```

My main problem is, that i have a session value which describes where i have to route my request. If there is a special value in, i would like to route my request to Location A, otherwise to Location B.

Is there another possibility to do that?

Comment: "I could only access the Key but not the session value." What do you mean? Is it null? That is how you would access the session. If it's null, then it hasn't been set.

Answer (score 8):

I have same issue, you can do something like below:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("user");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SessionCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("user") == "User One")
        {
            actionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "LocationA Controller",
                action = "LocationA Action",
                returnurl = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(actionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Request)
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            actionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "LocationB Controller",
                action = "LocationB Action",
                returnurl = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(actionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Request)
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

> Write `SessionCheck` class as above you can set your special value by typing  `HttpContext.Session.SetString("user", "User One");` in where you want to set also you can use multiple `if-elseif` like the same, This is working in **.Net Core 3.1**.